# How to fetch specific field value in array?

Tags: php

How to fetch specific field value from array? I have tried like below

```
            $studentarray2 =array();
            $studentarray2 = $cursor;
            echo  $key = array_search('student_id', $studentarray2);
```

It is not working!!!

```
  $studentarray2 contains 

         array(49) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#10 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "5715e59399fbad983700002b" } ["student_id"]=> float(22) ["registration_temp_perm_no"]=> string(5) "54321" ["roll_no"]=> string(2) "18" --- }
```

I am trying get student_id field from the above array which 22 in this example.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would try `$studentarray2['_id']->student_id`

Comment: Undefined property: MongoId::$student_id error is shown

Comment: Are you using `$stundent_id` insted of `student_id`?

Comment: It's an array, not an object. Try `$studentarray2['_id']['student_id']`